# FFMPEG real-time buffer full frame dropped

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

I'm using FFMPEG on windows with direct show.
I'm streaming RTMP (command below) and i need very low latency.
Once run I get the following errors: [dshow @ 024ce800] real-time buffer 204% full! frame dropped!

**ffmpeg** -threads 6 -f dshow -i video=UScreenCapture -s 1920x1080 -an -vco
dec libx264 -x264opts keyint=25:min-keyint=20 -b:v 1024k -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 22 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://server...

Do you have an idea how to handle this kind of error?

Thanks
Ronen

Answer (score 1):

That message means "dshow got an incoming packet, but you haven't finished sending the previous packet yet" so in reality, this should be contributing to as low a latency possible.  If your goal is to avoid dropping packets then increase rtbufsize.  With rtmp hopefully there will be some improvements soon so it has better throughput.